# 'not only reflected ..., but also the fact that ...'

Tags: style, parallelism

I found this sentence:

> Margaret Thatcher’s legendary nickname *Laura Norder* **not only reflected** her political preferences, **but also the fact** that, like most of her compatriots, she pronounces *law and order* with an intrusive /r/ between *law* and *and*.

<sup>(From: [Perception of intrusive /r/ in English by native, cross-language
and cross-dialect listeners](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:137983:10/component/escidoc:1093600/Tuinman_tmcJASA2011pdf.pdf). Annelie Tuinman, Holger Mitterer, Anne Cutler.)</sup>

Almost instantly, the use of *not only* and *but also* of the sentence jumped out right at me. My first instinct was like: this is incorrect, it should be *"reflected not only ..., but also the fact that, ..."*. (Another possibility I think possible is: *"Not only did Margaret Thatcher's legendary nickname ..., but also the fact that, ..."*.)

Then again, maybe I think too much, and it's not really incorrect, just a matter of style.

What is the right way to think of the sentence?

Comment: "Correctness" is not a matter of fact but of what the speaker cares about. ***I*** care about making sentences as unambiguous and easy to parse as possible, so I'm on the side of folks who say the sentence would be better if it were written *reflected not only A but also B*.

Comment: Thatcher was given several different nicknames, including **Milk Snatcher** (she discontinued the free school milk scheme), **Tina** ("There is no alternative" to her policies), **She Who Must Be Obeyed**, **Iron Lady** (by the Soviets, but UK media took it up too), **Attila the Hen**, and **Maggie** . But to the best of my knowledge, Laura Norder never had any particular currency in relation to her. It certainly wouldn't merit the "legendary" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When written as per your example (with extraneous verbiage stripped):

> [It] not only reflected her political preferences, but also the fact that [...] she pronounces law and order [that way].

The parallel construction isn't between "not only" and "but also", but between **not only reflected** and **but also [reflected]**.

It is as if there's a second implicit copy of the verb there, not unlike how in English we can say:

> She gave him the book, her the scroll, and the rest of them photocopies.

So:

> [It] not only reflected her political preferences, but also **[reflected]** the fact that [...] she pronounces law and order [that way].

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusingly structured, but the basic structure is

> *A* not only reflected *B*, but also *C*

Where A is

> Margaret Thatcher’s legendary nickname *Laura Norder*

B is

> her political preferences

and C is

> the fact that, like most of her compatriots, she pronounces *law and order* with an intrusive /r/ between *law* and *and*.

Me, I'd write it differently, but I'm not a Writer-with-a-capital-W.

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  A is "her political preferences", B is "the fact that [...] she pronounces [...]".

Comment: Whoops: got it all wrong. I'll fix it.